# Use gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf to compile .c file, What is the command?

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

I am doing cross compiling. I install the `gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and want to use it to compile the `.c` file(example of hello world) and then run it on ARM. I don't know what is the exact command. Commands like `gcc -c filenam.c` seem not correct.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

if you compile the c source file, you'll need to do like below:

```
gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnuebihf filenam.c -o filenam
```

through this, executable file with name '`filenam`' will be generated on your current folder.